# Transforming an assembly line into C

Tags: assembly, c

When I see the assembly line:

```
 MOV ESI, DWORD PTR DS:[EBP+0x8]
```

And, when Ollydbg shows me that `[EBP+0x8] = 00000000`, then can I write it in C like this:

```
 int *esi = NULL;
```

Or, should I use the stack address `EBP + 0x8` which is `0x0012FF43` and write something like:

```
 int *esi = &0012FF43
```

I would say that the first is the right answer, but I am very confused about that.

Answer (score 3):

Brackets mean 'contents of'... so it would be more like:

```
int esi = 0;
```

-or-

```
int esi = *(ebp+8); /* assuming ebp is correct */
```

-or-

```
int esi = (int)*(ebp+8); /* assuming ebp is (void*) or (char*)
                            we need to pull 4 bytes to get value */
```

I would hope that `(EBP+0x8)` would *not* be `0x12FF43`, as the stack pointer is supposed to be aligned to 4 or 8 byte addresses (4 for 32bit cpu's, 8 for 64bit, generally 16 byte aligned in 64bit though).

Odd to see a `DS:` modifier for the EBP register, as it's usually `SS:`, only works well if `DS=SS`, or both are `0`.  Nitpicky, but you have to be when playing that close to the metal.

Comment: Yes, can use EBP with DS:, just odd to see it used in a non-stack setting.  It's so very often used to set up a stack frame in functions, sometimes forget it's a regular full register.

Comment: It's pretty common to not have a frame pointer and use EBP as a general purpose register. After all, ia32 is extremely register starved. Btw pointer arithmetic on void pointers is illegal so the (void *) case up there would not work and the (char *) case would simply read a char and cast to int so it would be incorrect. You need to cast to (int *) before reading the value but add to a (char *). It might also be interesting to note that if the second translation of the assembly to C was correct you'd be very likely to see a LEA instruction instead of a MOV.

Answer (score 2):

`[EBX+8]` is the second `dword` variable of this stack frame. If it's being put in `esi` it's probably a pointer operation so maybe `memcpy(dest,src,0x100)` would include that line if `src` was set to `NULL` after being declared 
`char *src = argument;`.

That's the most realistic as you don't generally access esi directly from C.

Of course in my example, `memcpy` would segfault when `NULL` was dereferenced.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856320/purpose-of-esi-edi-registers

Answer (score 1):

`MOV ESI, DWORD PTR DS:[EBP+0x8]`

*Load 4 bytes from `EBP+0x8` into `ESI`.*

`ESI` does not become a pointer unless `[EBP+0x8]` holds an address, so without knowing that, you cant really know if you should set `ESI` to `NULL`.

Its helpful while reading assembly to translate each line into C but sometimes you need to understand what types are used in the rest of the code to convert it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a misunderstand here. `ESI` is a register not a variable, so:

```
int *esi = NULL;
```

If you want to assign value to `esi` in C, you should use the inline assembly brackets `asm {}`.

Also, usually in OllyDbg `MOV ESI, DWORD PTR DS:[EBP+0x8]` line appears at the beginning of functions like that:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
push esi
mov esi, [ebp +8]
...
```

That means `esi` will get the pointer of first argument of function. So, to write your line in C language, you should write a function with at least one parameter. The first parameters you pass to this functions will be value of `esi`.

Answer (score 0):

let's say for example:
`EBP = 00100000`

then:
`EBP+8 = 00100008`

then the code become:
`MOV ESI, DWORD PTR DS:[00100008]`

this means copy to the register `ESI` the dword that located in the address `00100008`

so you could write `MOV ESI, DWORD PTR DS:[00100008]` in c as:

`int esi = *0x00100008;`